# Wicket JavaScript is not getting reflected

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui, wicket-6, wicket-7, wicket-8

I am facing a weird behavior in the wicket pages of the below hierarchy.

RootPage with few Abstract tabs added and In few Abstract tabs, based on the use case we have TabbedPanel of wicket UI Jquery. like this http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/tabs/TabbedPanelPage?2. To navigate between tabs, I use AjaxTabbedPanel.

**Issue1:** Even the Default Jquery file is getting added to the page. But the UI components are not rendered with respect to Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.resource.JQueryResourceReference/jquery/jquery-2.2.4-ver-F9EE266EF993962AD59E804AD9DEBE66.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/com.googlecode.wicket.jquery.ui.resource.JQueryUIResourceReference/jquery-ui-ver-0A819924D70A18322660DEE759225D2B.js"></script>
```

To overcome the above issue I have added the Jquery file by overriding renderHead method in RootPage. **which only works on manual page refresh.**

**RootPage.renderHead:**

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response){
 super.render(response);
 response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(new PackageResourceReference(RootPage.class, "jquery.min.js")));
 response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(new PackageResourceReference(RootPage.class, "jquery-ui.min.js")));
}
```

**Issue2:** But since I made Ajax to navigate between tabs, refreshing page using`setResponsePage()` seems to be an unexpected way.

To solve the Issue1, I explicitly added jquery which lead to another problem of an explicit refresh.

Am I missing anything in the **Issue1** which can solve the issue?
or Is there any way to refresh only my panels? to fix **Issue2**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you contribute jquery.js yourself?

I'm not sure whether this is the cause of your problem but since Wicket also adds jQuery to the DOM I think you might have Javascript errors. Check the browser's DevTools console.

Comment: Thanks, edit the question to elaborate my exact issue